# Is it possible to stream input into RAR

Tags: backup, archive, rar

I'm using RARLABS RAR.exe to archive/backup my server data.  I am familiar with using RAR for creating an archive and adding files from a folder, but what about streaming data directly into an archive?

For example, when backing up my MySQL databases I use the mysqldump command that includes a pipe command into a text file.  It would be nice to skip the file step and go directly into an archive file using something like the following syntax:

```
mysqldump -uUserName -pPassword --all-databases > rar.exe newarchivename.rar
```

Does anyone know if what I have described, or something similar, is even possible?

Comment: What platform?  Windows/*nix?  I believe you could do something with a named pipe.

Comment: Yeah, it's a Windows platform...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I contacted RARLabs support and recieved a response.  It turns out that RAR.EXE **can** handle streaming input similar to how gzip works.  You just need to specify the -si option:

```
   -si[name]
     Read data from stdin (standard input), when creating
     an archive. Optional 'name' parameter allows to specify
     a file name of compressed stdin data in the created
     archive. If this parameter is missing, the name will be
     set to 'stdin'. This switch cannot be used with -v.
```

Why would I want to use RAR instead of GZIP?  Well one thing GZIP doesn't have is the ability to automatically include a date stamp on the file name.

So with this info here is an example of how I will be backing up the MySQL database information:

```
mysqldump --all-databases | rar a -siWordPressDB.sql -ag_MMMDDYYYY-HHMM WordPressDB.sql.rar
```

Which creates an archive file that looks similar to the following name:

```
WordPressDB.sql_Feb242010-0938.rar
```

and contains a single file:

```
WordPressDB.sql
```

Pretty cool...

Comment: nice, didn't know it could do that (none of my versions of rar support the -si option.. time to upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, exactly what I'm looking for, this makes rar much more usefull.

> nice, didn't know it could do that (none of my versions of rar support the -si option.. time to upgrade) – James Feb 24 at 19:07

This function is at least available since v3.71

For some reason this function isn't in the manual.
You can find this information and more in the rar.txt file.
 (*nix) Usually in /usr/share/doc/rar (rar.txt or rar.txt.gz)